# php numeric array processing

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to process an array from data posted from a textbox.
I've written the following code to trim each new line and I have nearly everything working perfectly except one thing. I believe I need to iterate my numeric array through this GeoIP function:
`$record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi,$value);`, but it only processes the last IP in the array, and not the entire thing.

My var_dump: string(12) "65.87.12.213" string(12) "13.15.200.36"

```
$gi = geoip_open("/tmp/GeoIPCity.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

$iips = explode("\n", $_POST["ip"]);
$iiips=array_map('trim',$iips);
foreach($iiips as $key => $value) {
    $record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi,$value);
}
print $record->city . "\n";
print $record->region . " " . "\n";
print $record->country_name . "\n";

$record1 = $record->city . " " . $record->region . " " . $record->country_name;

var_dump($record1);
```

Is there anybody that can please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `foreach` loop you overwrite the `$record` variable all the time, so at the end you have the last one.

Store all records into another array instead and you should be fine.

So this is just a more or less simple mistake you made.

```
$records = array();
foreach ($iiips as $key=>$value) {
    $records[] = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $value);
}

foreach ($records as $record) {

    echo $record->city, "\n",
         $record->region, "\n",
         $record->country_name, "\n";

    $record_string = $record->city . " " . $record->region . " " . $record->country_name;

    var_dump($record_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$record =  geoip_record_by_addr($gi,$value);`, do this:

```
$record = array();
foreach($iiips as $value) { // key isnt needed.
    array_push($record, geoip_record_by_addr($gi,$value));
}
```

Then you're free to use the contents of `$record` as you expected. Re-assigning a variable in any loop will change the value of that specific variable each time. PHP doesn't know that you're using an array unless you tell it.